# How to multiply entire row with a matching row name in another dataframe?

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have the following dataframes:

```
    test <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3), Y = c(4,5,6), row.names = c("T1", "T2", "T3"))

    test2 <- data.frame(mean = c(1,2,5), row.names = c("T1", "T2", "T3"))
```

I want to multiply all rows in the test dataframe by the value in the test2 dataframe, matched by row name. How do I do this to get an answer like this:

```
    answer <- data.frame(X = c(1,4,15), Y = c(4,10,30), row.names = c("T1", "T2", "T3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
x <- test %>% 
      rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
      left_join(test2 %>% rownames_to_column("id"), by = "id") %>%
      mutate_at(vars(colnames(test)), list(~ . * mean)) %>% 
      select(-mean)
```

if you have columns with the same names (e.g. two columns called X), then they will be labelled X.1 and X.2
If you want to get rid of the fullstop and everything after it, I would do:

```
colnames(x) <- str_replace(colnames(x),"\\..*","")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
test * test2[rownames(test), "mean"]
#     X  Y
# T1  1  4
# T2  4 10
# T3 15 30
```

Comment: Not using `dplyr` here. Let me know if you don't need that and I delete the answer.

Comment: I keep getting the following error:
`Error in Ops.data.frame(UCO1, tpm_Fed_all[rownames(UCO1), "mean_tpm"]) : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

Comment: @Marcus I can only guess from the error, but does `tpm_Fed_all[rownames(UCO1), "mean_tpm"])` return a vector? I guess you are using a tibble in which case you should do `tpm_Fed_all[rownames(UCO1), "mean_tpm", drop = TRUE])`

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert rownames to column first and then join and do any aggregation you need, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
 rownames_to_column('id') %>% 
 left_join(test2 %>% rownames_to_column('id'), by = 'id') %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(c('X', 'Y')), list(~ . * mean)) %>% 
 select(-mean)

#  id  X  Y
#1 T1  1  4
#2 T2  4 10
#3 T3 15 30
```

Answer (score 3):

Just posting because I was already working on it. Almost same solution as @Sotos, but with `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  left_join(test2 %>% rownames_to_column()) %>% 
  mutate(across(X:Y, ~.*mean)) %>% 
  select(-mean)

Joining, by = "rowname"
  rowname  X  Y
1      T1  1  4
2      T2  4 10
3      T3 15 30
```

Comment: suppose there were over 100 columns, is there anyway to automate without having to mention the column names (i.e X:Y)

Comment: If they are all next to each other you can just do `name_of_column_1:name_of_column_2`

Comment: I trying to incorporate this into a bigger script and sometimes the column names might be duplicated, hence why I'm trying to avoid having to name column names

Comment: You could use `where(is.numeric)` inside `across` to apply to multiplication to all numeric variables. Like this you do not need the names, but of course only makes sense if you want to multiply all numeric varialbes with `mean`